# MacOS X TrueType fonts with X11

Tags: xorg, truetype-fonts, gimp, macos

Is there a simple way to install TTF fonts on macos X so that they work with X11 (and Gimp) ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Font Book(located in `/Applications/Font Book.app`) you can install TTF fonts for just yourself(`~/Library/Fonts`), or system wide(`/Library/Fonts`). Once installed, X11 should recognize them after you adjust its font cache or editing its configuration file: [Instructions](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-fonts.html#TRUETYPE).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing them into `~/.fonts/`? That's the standard path for *NIX platforms, and **should** work for X11 in OS X. Haven't tried it myself, tho.